# What's the difference between service context and object context?

Tags: service, objectcontext

I am having trouble in understanding what is the difference between the service context and the object context.

I mean, where are they used? What is the basic difference?

Comment: Hard to answer without context...

Comment: @Turbo J:should i give you an example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> `ObjectContext` is a class that is
>   generated inside the generated
>   `DomainService` class that you made.

while

Object Services is a component of the Entity Framework that enables you to query, insert, update, and delete data, expressed as strongly typed CLR objects that are instances of entity types. Object Services supports both Language-Integrated Query (LINQ) and Entity SQL queries against types that are defined in an Entity Data Model (EDM). Object Services materializes returned data as objects, and propagates object changes back to the data source. It also provides facilities for tracking changes, binding objects to controls, and handling concurrency. Object Services is implemented by classes in the [System.Data.Objects](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.objects%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) and [System.Data.Objects.DataClasses](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.objects.dataclasses%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) namespaces.

Comment: are object service and service context same?